# .split() won't work when I try to parse a variable

Tags: javascript

I am turning `window.location` into a variable and I am trying to split it but it won't work. Does anyone know why?

If I do `alert(window.location)` it gives me:

`http://localhost/instagramAjax.php#access_token=asd7.032033f.90c7de9easdab96d880799c34d10f`

So I do this, but it doesn't work. It just kills my javascript.

```
var token = window.location;
token = token.split("#access_token=");
alert(token[1]);
```

Comment: Someone already answered that location does't work like that, but that said...What is it with people abusing ```split``` for parsing and blindly grabbing array elements. Regexs are a *much* better tool for the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Location is technically an object, use `window.location.href`, which is the string value.  [Here's more info if you're interested.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Comment: @bryan happy to help.  Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark if it works for you.

Comment: I would, but I have to wait until 15min is up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read fragment strings after '#', instead of parsing `location.href` you may simply use this:

```
window.location.hash
```

Similarly, you can use the following to read query strings after '?' :

```
window.location.search
```